# Как работать со списком в этом случае?

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть 2 списка.

```
list_1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
list_2 = ["Игрок","Повар","Моряк","Солдат"]
```

Мне не обходимо совместить объекты из 2 списков таким образом.

```
1 - Игрок
2 - Повар
3 - Моряк
4 - Солдат

5 - Игрок
6 - Повар
7 - Моряк
8 - Солдат

9 - Игрок
10 - Повар
```

Comment: "Домашние задания надо выполнять самостоятельно. Если у вас возник вопрос по домашнему заданию, не просите его сделать за вас. Задайте конкретный вопрос о проблеме, которую вы не можете решить. Программирование — это то, в чём надо разбираться самому, либо не заниматься им вовсе. Если для вас программирование — лишний предмет в учебной программе, есть сайты и люди на этих сайтах, выполняющие задания за материальное вознаграждение. Здесь предлагать выполнить работу за вас и наоборот — моветон." https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь функциями `zip` и `cycle`:

```
from itertools import cycle

list_1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
list_2 = ["Игрок","Повар","Моряк","Солдат"]

print(dict(zip(list_1, cycle(list_2))))

# {1: 'Игрок', 2: 'Повар', 3: 'Моряк', 4: 'Солдат', 
#  5: 'Игрок', 6: 'Повар', 7: 'Моряк', 8: 'Солдат', 9: 'Игрок', 10: 'Повар'}
```

Если в итоге нужен список, а не словарь, то:

```
list(zip(list_1, cycle(list_2)))
# [(1, 'Игрок'), (2, 'Повар'), (3, 'Моряк'), (4, 'Солдат'), 
#  (5, 'Игрок'), (6, 'Повар'), (7, 'Моряк'), (8, 'Солдат'), (9, 'Игрок'), (10, 'Повар')]
```

Comment: Все получилось, спасибо )

Comment: это не домашнее задание )
У меня возникла проблема с веб проектом, решил применить другой метод